# re.findall - how to get the main matched expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

An expression like:

```
re.findall("a(.*?)b",'..a12b..a23b..a45b..')
```

gives me only the grouped matches: `['12', '23', '45']`.

How do I also get the a base matches, ie `['a12b', 'a23b', 'a45b']`?

Of course I could type them in manually, but is there an easier way like the equivalent of `matches[0]` in other languages?

Comment: You mean besides changing the capture group? Or adding a capture group? Or in this case, just doing `['a' + match + 'b' for match in matches]`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the parenthesis. That's what is returned.

```
>>> re.findall("a.*?b",'..a12b..a23b..a45b..')
['a12b', 'a23b', 'a45b']
```

Add another pair for

```
>>> re.findall("(a(.*?)b)",'..a12b..a23b..a45b..')
[('a12b', '12'), ('a23b', '23'), ('a45b', '45')]
>>> zip(*_)
[('a12b', 'a23b', 'a45b'), ('12', '23', '45')]
```

Note ( _ in the interpreter gets the last outputted value)

Comment: Thanks. That gave me the idea of nesting of groups, and it works!  `re.findall("(a(.*?)b)", '..a12b..a23b..a45b..')` achieved exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You beat me to the `zip()` method, so I just deleted my answer :).

Comment: `full_match, inner_match = zip(*re.findall('a(.*?)b)', string))`

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) said

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

So just remove the `()` so that it could return entire pattern.

```
re.findall("a.*?b",'..a12b..a23b..a45b..')
```

If you have to use group, use non-capturing group:

```
re.findall("a(?:.*?)b",'..a12b..a23b..a45b..')
```